# How can I save my smart phone screen from finger spots?

Tags: cleaning, cell-phone

Fingers spots in smart phone screen make my phone unsecure. Because people can easily draw pattern because of these fingers spots. How can I save my cell phone screen from these fingers spots?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your phone does not already have oleophobic coating on the screen, the easiest way to fight against fingerprint marks on the screen is to buy [oleophobic screen protector](https://youtu.be/vC5Uu8JAkMY?t=27).

Olephobic means that there is a thin coating on the screen that repels water, dirt and for your case most important, oil marks.

Also, look at [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/18467/how-can-i-remove-skin-oil-from-my-phones-screen?rq=1) that is similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stylus, or use the screen with your finger knuckle (the part most people knock on a door with) instead of your finger tip. Finger tips are great at leaving marks because you touch everything else with them and, in most people, they have a lot of sweat glands